# What are the differences between Framework and Package in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks, package

**What are the differences between Framework and Package in Swift?**

I knew about differences of swift embeddable components like,

1. Static Framework
2. Static Library
3. Dynamic Framework
4. Dynamic Library

But I do not know what is the purpose of the Swift Package?
**When should I use Swift package?**

Answer (score 1):

In Swift, packages are [reusable components of Swift, Objective-C, Objective-C++, C, or C++ code that developers can use in their projects](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift_packages). This is similar to packages in [npm](https://www.npmjs.com).

Packages are primarily distributed through [Cocoa Pods](http://cocoapods.org), [Swift Package Manager](https://www.github.com/apple/swift-package-manager), and [Carthage](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage).

Packages can contain Frameworks and Libraries and can use other packages as dependencies.

You would use a package in Swift when you want to re-use a piece of code in different projects as you would an npm package in Javascript projects. An example would be [NetworkUtils](https://github.com/RyuGames/NetworkUtils) a package distributed on Cocoa Pods that provides networking support.

Packages are just a way to distribute code, like a framework or a library. The benefit comes from how easy it is to manage them. You can manage a list of the dependencies you want to include and the package manager will handle downloading and installing the code into your project for you. It also makes it easier to choose specific versions of packages to use in your project.

For example, if I want to include `NetworkUtils` in my project, I would just edit a `Podfile` (a Cocoa Pods file for managing dependencies) and would just add a line: `pod 'NetworkUtils'` and then run the `pod install` command in terminal and it would load the newest version of the package into my project.

Comment: That means all the pods I am using in my project are packages but I have been calling them pod frameworks from the beginning.. I was wrong?

Comment: Cocoa Pods refer to them as pods as opposed to packages. Carthage I guess does refer to code distributed through it as frameworks — so I guess it would be more accurate to call them dependency managers rather than package managers. In Cocoa Pods (I don't really have too much experience with the others), you can distribute all kinds of code (libraries, frameworks, and even just reusable snippets of code).

Comment: The code distributed through Cocoa Pods isn't always compiled code, while a `.framework` is compiled code where you can really just see the function headers and not their implementations.